# test for convergence in this series $(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm testing for convergence in this series:

$(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n!}$

I approached it with the ratio-test, although is there a better way to test for convergence in alternating series?

This is what I've done so far:

$$(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n+1+1}n!}{(-1)^n(n+1)!2^{2n+1}}$$

Then cancelling the terms:
$$-\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{1}{2}$$ The series converges to $-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: It converges to $2e^{-4}$

Comment: I would have never guessed that! could you show me a proof for it?

Comment: For alternating series there is another test. If you consider the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} (-1)^n a_n$, the series converges if $a_n$ is strictly decreasing and converges to zero. There are cases where this criteria is even easier than other tests.

Comment: Series is $2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{n!}$ which is immediately recognizable as the series for exponential function and the proof follows similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That last sequence converges to zero, which means the convergence radius of the absolute value of the sequence's series is infinite...and thus the alternating series (what you have) converges. You also cancelled incorrectly:

$$\frac{2^{2(n+1)+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{2^{2n+1}}=\frac4{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies R=\infty$$

and if you want to know the series sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n!}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{n!}=2e^{-4}$$

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown on the sum! It's opened my eyes on recognising the pattern for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could notice that the series is a modification of the Taylor series of e^-x,

e^-x = sigma of (-1)^n * (x^n)/n!

First we will simplify the series
sigma of (-1)^n * (2^(1+2n))/n!
= 2 * sigma of (-1)^n * (2^(2n))/n!
-- Here we just take out a multiplication of a constant out of the sum

= 2 * sigma of (-1)^n * (4^n)/n!
-- By using the identity, 2^(2n) = 2^2^n = 4^n

Therefore, 2*e^-4 = 2 * sigma of (-1)^n * (4^n)/n! = sigma of (-1)^n * (2^(1+2n))/n!

Working with Taylor expansions can subtract our need to calculate the limit of some tests (which sometimes can be a tedious work), the series does not converge to -1/2,

Using the ratio test you'd need to calculate the lim of a_(n+1) / a_(n) in absolute value, I mean lim of |a_(n+1) / a_(n)|, if that limit is less than 1 then you know that the series converges but that limit does not indicate to what it converges to, only that it converges.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of LaTeX notation :)